# Deriving smoothing kernels

Tags: fluid-dynamics, lagrangian-formalism, differentiation, calculus

I'm watching [a video](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/750764/nabla-cdot-nabla-nabla-cdot-nabla2-what-do-they-do) on smoothed particle hydrodynamics it just blindly claims that these smoothing kernels are pretty good.

$$W(r-r_b,h)\equiv\dfrac{315}{64\pi h^9}\left(h^2-|r-r_b|^2\right)^3$$
$$\nabla W(r-r_b,h)\equiv\dfrac{-45}{\pi h^6}\left(h-|r-r_b|\right)^2\left(\dfrac{r-r_b}{|r-r_b|}\right)$$
$$\nabla^2W\equiv\dfrac{45}{\pi h^6}\left(h-|r-r_b|\right)$$

However, it provides no citation, nor does it explain how each of these terms are derived.

Where do these come from?

Comment: Have you looked at Wikipedia? For instance [Kernel smoother](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_smoother), [Kernel (statistics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)), etc.

Comment: I hadn't, but I just have and neither of your links seem to show where these particular values come from... I'm not asking *what* a smoothing kernel is... I'm asking where the values for this one come from

Comment: Looks pretty close to the quartic biweights to me, but what do I know.

Comment: Does it? The Quartic Biweight in the link is $K(u)=\dfrac{15}{16}}(1-u^2)^2$ admittedly, I could be missing some important information to join the dots here, SPH is very new to me

Comment: Whoops, I should have said the tri-weight, not biweight. Either way, the information you're missing is in the articles.

Comment: But judging from your [other question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/750764/25301), you may have more problems than just "SPH is new to me" like learning vector calculus and fluid dynamics, which is a large undertaking in itself.

Comment: @KyleKanos - Sure, I'm working on that, but knowing vector calculus isn't going to tell me where these values come from is it? I'm not inclined to hold off on asking questions just because I have something related to it still to learn. Also, yes, the terms are similar, but not the same... Are these essentially just experimentally obtained terms that just happen to work quite well?

Answer (score 1):

To be clear, there is only *one* [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)) listed in that trio of equations,
$$W(r-r_b,\,h)\sim h^{-9}\left(h^2-\vert r-r_b\vert^2\right)^3.\tag{1}$$
The latter two equations are the [gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) (first derivative) and [laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator) (second derivative) of the kernel, $W(r-r_b,\,h)$. In this kernel, $r$ and $r_b$ are the centroids of the computational particles while $h$ is the scale distance such that if $||r-r_b||>h$, the kernel yields zero (which would physically mean that the two particles are separated by such a distance so as to not interact).

If you define $u=\vert r-r_b\vert/h$, then we can write Eq (1) as,
$$W(u)\sim h^{-3}\left(1-u^2\right)^3$$
which takes the form of the *tri-weight* kernel listed in the first Wikipedia link. In order to make it fully equal, you need to use the fact that kernels are normalized over all space,
$$\int W(r-r_b,\,h)\,\mathrm{d}V\equiv1,$$
(as well as symmetric about the centroid, but I think that's nothing to worry about right here). If you apply this normalization condition in the correct geometry (I'm assuming 3D spherical coordinates), you should arrive at the same formula the source lists for you.

See also:

- [Kernel normalization in Smoothed Particle Hydrodynamcs](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/138700/25301)

---

In terms of deriving a function $W(r,\,h)$, you must satisfy the two properties of the kernel function (symmetry & normalization), but it is also useful to ensure that,

- it is compactly supported (i.e., its domain is $[-h,\,h]$ such that $W(r,\,h)=0$ for $|r|>h$.
- it is strictly positive ($W(r,\,h)\geq0$ for all $r$) with (at least) two continuous derivatives
- it is monotonically decreasing from the centroid ($r=0$)
- it should approach the [Dirac delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) as $h\to0$

For use in numerical codes, you also want something that can be efficiently computed, since this function would be invoked many times for each time step in the evolution, with each operation in the function adding time to the simulation runtime.
In this case, I imagine that the author's made the claim because the cubic function performs well enough that higher-order functions are less common, though I've not been involved in any SPH research work for a long time.